# Automator: Filter finder items by date modified isn't working as expected

Tags: finder, automator

I am using automator to move all finder items in a location to trash if their last date modified is after 2 weeks from today.

The workflow is as follows:

Get Specified Finder Items (an external hard drive) - *works well*

Get Folder Contents (repeat for each subfolder found) - *works well*

Filter Finder Items (all that are not a folder) - *works well*

Filter Finder Items (all whose date modified is not in the last 2 weeks) - *DOES NOT WORK*
*This passes all the items to the next process without any being filtered*

Move Finder Items to Trash - *works well*

**I am able to make this workflow work correctly if the condition for the Filter is set to "All items whose date modified is after a specific date". Here, I manually input the date which is 14 days before today.**

Can anyone explain why these two functions cause the filter to behave differently when they are essentially the exact same thing?

I want to have the 2 week condition so that I can run the workflow without having to edit it every time.

Thanks!
Cake

Answer (score 2):

I'd use the `find` *command* instead.

In a new **Automator** *workflow*, add the following *actions*:

- **Run Shell Script**

  - Settings - **Shell:** `/bin/bash` *and* **Pass input:** `to stdin`
  - Replace the default `cat` with:

    ```
    find "/Path/To/Directoty" -type f -mtime +14d -iname '*.*'
    ```
  - Change `"/Path/To/Directory"` to the *pathname* of the *target directory*, e.g. `"/Volumes/Name/Directory/.."`
- **Move Finder Items to Trash**
- Save the *workflow* as an *application*.

  - Test that this does as you want before saving it as an application.

Note: You could devise a more complex `find` *command* and or *workflow*, however this, as is, is better then your current malfunctioning workflow.